# PL/SQL, condition at the begin of function/procedure

Tags: if-statement, plsql

I know, that it is not good, when you use condition in body of function/procedure

```
FUNCTION xyz (...) IS

BEGIN
  IF a=1 THEN

       ....

  END IF;
END;
```

---

This is not really effective, because all of logic in this function run only when the condition is true.
is there solution to do that better?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why do you think using an `IF` in the body is a bad thing? You can't use it anywhere else.

Comment: When you write your logic in database, how can make it without IF-THEN-ELSE or CASE statement?

Comment: becouse it is not really effective, IF is ok, but there is problem, that all of logic is doing only if condition is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the solution.

Better mainly for reading and understanding of code is when you use this:

```
FUNCTION xyz (...) IS
BEGIN
  IF a!=1 THEN
    return null;
  END IF;
  .....

END;
```